# Highlight Empty Lines in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

For the purpose of simple sorting, not specifically coding, I would find it very useful to make an obvious horizontal divider by making a single or double linebreak between entries a different color. Simply as an at a glance way to see how many separate sets I've made.

This would mean if the line is completely empty, containing no visible or invisible characters. The highlight would color the entire width of the horizontal space. It would not change the colors after, remaining only in the empty area. Additionally, if possible, it would be disabled if there are multiple empty lines in a row.

Are there any plugins or settings that can allow me to do this?

Comment: Not really, the answer would be the closest thing I'm pretty sure. Bunch of other programs can do this with ease.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find empty lines.

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- Find what: `^\h*\R`
- Select `Bookmark line`
- Search mode: `Regular Expression`
- Press <kbd>Mark All</kbd>

The empty lines will be marked with a blue circle on the left side of the editor.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the answer! That's definitely a backup solution of sorts.

But I was hoping for something that happens as I type, and is more visually noticeable. Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: BTW, \r\n\r\n using *Extended*, also works.